# How do i remove the white spaces in my text file using c program

Tags: c

How do i remove the white spaces in my text file ? The reason to work behind it, my colleague,  he has lots of text files with huge amount of white spaces between them. Its getting harder for him to remove them by hitting backspace.So what i planned is to write a code to that.And i was successful upto 99%. Check up the below code that i have written.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int b;
    char array[100];
    gets(array); \\ file name to be given here
    FILE *P;
    FILE *T;
    P=fopen(array,"r");
    T=fopen("./duplicate.txt","w");
    for(;(b=getc(P))!=EOF;)
    {
        if(b==32)
        {
            fputc(b,T);
            me:
            b=getc(P);
            if(b==32)
            goto me;
        }
        fputc(b,T);
    }
}
```

The code working perfect but the thing I did it, by creating a duplicate of original text file.But i dont want to make duplicate , I want to rewrite to the original file itself. I tried it to the original text file.But some where its going wrong.

I have the algorithm how to approach it like saving the strings and writing them back to file but i think that is not the efficient approach. And guys i have a doubt

```
fputs("\b",filepointer);
```

will these create a backspace I suppose no is the answer. because its writing the backspace character not performing the backspace operation.But i think there is a function ungetc() will it work here.Any ideas would be rewarded.Thank you

Comment: format the code properly, please.

Comment: Brace yourself.  Someone is bound to comment on the statement sequence:  `char array[100]; gets(array);`

Comment: You still have time to remove that `goto` without anyone noticing the edit. Quick!

Comment: Did not get you.Is there any problem using gets() over there.?

Comment: why to remove the goto? Im not getting you guys but it is working fine right?

Comment: @niko: `goto` statements have their uses, what you have there is not one of them.  Use a looping construct: `while`, `do`/`while` or something.  `do`/`while` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: But i guess do while wont work suppose if i have like these " hello   6 spaces world \newline 4 spaces  what 10 spaces  your" I think  12 spaces  do while wont  8 spaces work ?

Comment: Why do you need to use C?  Unless the files are tens of megabytes I would think perl or ruby would be just fine.

Comment: @David Not everyone knows Perl or Ruby. (I don't.)

Comment: so people suggest me perl?  But i wanna make the things in c .Just improving my skills more and more in c.I have done it using perl but I wanna make it in c thats my aim and desire.

Comment: Niko I see you have removed the gets() and changed it to scanf(). Is that because it's your actual code, or because of @Ray's comment? Always show us your actual code.

Comment: @niko that's perfectly fine. you should clarify in your question that you're also aiming at practicing your skills with C, so we don't waste our and your time commenting on the tool choice.

Comment: ok bart! Let me change to my original format

Comment: oops sorry wihelmtell ! never do that again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would agree other posters there are much better choices then C for this, and you have several security and design problems, I'm going to answer your original question.

---

You cannot *directly* edit the file in place, because you are not simply changing what is there - you are changing the length and the structure; because of this, at some point you *will* be copying: either to memory or to a second file.
`malloc()` a buffer that is the size of the original file (because worst case it cannot be more, best case is much smaller) and read your characters in to memory. When done, `fopen()` your original file with the "**w**" flag and write everything back. I would normally recommend you make a copy and then delete-rename, but that appears to not be what a solution you are willing to accept based on your other comments.
**A warning, though**: during the time you have reopened your file and the time you have written everything back, you risk losing data.

Answer (score 1):

You have serious issues of security (`gets()`), design (`goto`) and choice of tools (this is a job for a scripting language, really) to begin with. But to answer you question, copy your `duplicate.txt` file over the original file.

Comment: Yes i thought the same but still i wanna make it over the original file without the help of duplicat file.

Comment: For all practical purposes, you can't. You have two choices: construct your text in memory and then write it over the original file, or write into a new file and then move the new file over the original file.

Comment: To clarify, this isn't a C limitation; it's how the file system works.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file for reading/writing and give a try:

```
P=fopen(array,"r+");
```

See more info about [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to sharpen your C skills, but if you install ruby then you could help your colleague with this one-liner at the command prompt which edits the file in place:

```
ruby -p -i -e '$_.squeeze!' file.txt
```

And if you want to make a backup file named `file.txt.backup` then:

```
ruby -p -i.backup -e '$_.squeeze!' file.txt
```

I think this will even work if you supply multiple file names on the end, so you could get fancy:

```
ruby -p -i -e '$_.squeeze!' *
```

or

```
ruby -p -i -e '$_.squeeze!' `find -name '*.txt'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You tempted me to write it. Don't look if you don't want spoilers.

https://gist.github.com/1096670